# Windows 8 store certificate: Uploaded app package invalid because of certification (publisher id)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I receive following error when attempting to upload my app to the Windows 8 store:

> Validation error:    The Publisher attribute of the Identity element
>   in the app manifest doesn't match your publisher ID, which is:
>   CN=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

I manually updated the app manifest file with the publisher id displayed within the error message.
However, the value that I provided ended up getting overwritten when I uploaded the file to the store  second time.

In conclusion, I am unable to upload my solution to the Windows 8 store because of a certificate issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a lot to go on here. I suspect you may have missed a step.  Did you associate your application with the Windows Store?

To do so, right click on your project in the solution explorer in Visual Studio. Select *Store* --> *Associate App With the Store...* Then follow the dialogs that come up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped me with certificate problems.

Comment: And when is it for another store that is not part of my account?