# Validation error:The following display name doesn't match any of your reserved names:Something

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows, windows-store

I am trying to upload a window app into the window app store,

While uploading the packages of the application i am facing following errors,

**Validation error:   The following display name doesn't match any of your reserved names:
9848centaur.Something**

**Validation error:   The Publisher attribute of the Identity element in the app manifest doesn't match your publisher ID, which is: CN=Something**

`The manifest file looks like`

[image]

I found out the errors are in the manifest file .

but i am not getting how to solve it since very less information is available

i have tried out the solutions posted by the following links,

http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2013/02/14/windows-store-apps-validation-error-publisher-attribute-doesn-t-match.aspx

http://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/windows-8-resolving-package-upload-errors/

i am following all the steps , still not getting rid of these validations .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad i found the Solution ,

I Checked [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843968/windows-8-store-certificate-uploaded-app-package-invalid-because-of-certificati) link

And the solution was simple

Right click on your project in the solution explorer in Visual Studio.

Select Store --> Associate App With the Store... Then follow the dialogs that come up.

Thanks Anyways.

Comment: I  have  migrated  my  app  from  WP 8.0  to   WP 8.1  Silverlight . Im  not  getting (Asssociate app with   store  option.)   Im  getting   Launch Windows App certification Kit..Please  help